# Using numeric keyboard on EditText in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, keyboard, android-keypad

I'm using an EditText in my android app, and I want a numeric keyboard to show when I tap and try to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two easy ways to do it, add one of the following to EditText block in XML file:

1. To get a Numeric dial keyboard pad

```
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:digits="1234567890"
```

2. To get the Numeric section of keyboard

```
        android:inputType="number"
```